# bash - Assign all files ending in .suite when no parameters are passed to script

Tags: bash

I have a script which you can pass test suites as parameters to:

```
$ bash-specs a.suite b.suite
```

If the user doesn't supply any test suites, all the test suites in the current folder shall be executed. This is how I do this currently:

```
local suites

if (($# > 0)); then
  suites=$@
else
  suites=*.suite
fi
```

This is an okay solution but I have a feeling there is a more elegant way. I basically look for some way to do a conditional assignment or setting a default value if no parameters are given.

Comment: Note that `*.suites` won't match filenames that end in `.suite` without the final `s`.

Comment: @MarkReed Thx, that was indeed a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
if (( ! $# )); then
    set -- *.suite
fi
```

Now you have the filenames in $1, $2, etc. no matter whether the user specified them or let them default.

Some notes:

Your assignment to `suites` doesn't seem to result in anything useful; it's not an array, so you get either a string with space-separated file names, or the unexpanded glob `"*.suites"`.  I'm guessing you somehow wind up `eval`ing that later on, but that's a bad idea - any spaces or funky characters in the file names will screw things up.  I recommend looping over the arguments and handling them individually, or using an actual array.

If you use something like my snippet above, `"$@"` will expand to all the arguments, properly separated as if individually quoted.  If you are going to be mucking with the arguments, you can save the original arguments in an array variable like so:

```
suites=( "$@" )
```

And then retrieve the whole thing (again, properly separated) with `"${suites[@]}"`.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: before using this answer, please read the comments for a discussion of its shortcomings and how it is actually expanded.

Short and sweet:

```
local suites=${@:-*.suite}
```

(Pun half-intended)

You can read more about the `${var:-default}` syntax in the `bash` man page under "Parameter Expansion". The whole section is well worth reading.

Edit: As Mark points out, if you did have spaces in your file names, then a string-valued `suites` wouldn't be very useful (you'd lose the distinction between separator-spaces and in-name spaces). I'd go with his answer. (Also, I've edited this to remove the quotes, as the pattern doesn't expand inside quotes.)

(I'm about one edit away from just deleting this answer :)

Comment: Will that glob actually expand for you inside quotes? or you plan for it to be expanded when used?

Comment: Inside the quotes. If `$@` is null or unset, the word following `:-` undergoes pattern expansion before assigning its value to `suites`.

Comment: This is not the behavior I see, fwiw.  If I go to a dir that contains some `.jpg` files, and say `echo "${unset:-*.jpg}"` I see `*.jpg`. I have to throw an `eval` out front to make it expand.

Comment: Even without the quotes, it won't expand. `x=${@:-*.lrn}; echo "$x"` results in `*.lrn`.  Of course, `echo $x` without the quotes will give you the list of filenames that match as of the echo, but that's different.

Comment: Huh. I could have sworn I tested that with quotes. Without quotes, it will expand as long as there is at least one matching file or `nullglob` is set.

Comment: There are matching files, but it still doesn't expand.  `$ echo *.lrn; x=${@:-*.lrn}; echo "$x"` results in `bug.lrn losers.lrn standard.lrn suicide.lrn` for the first echo and `*.lrn` for the second.

Comment: OK, I see now. The word following :- is *not* subject to pattern expansion, and so is assigned to the variable. It's the value of the unquoted variable after parameter expansion that undergoes pattern expansion.

Comment: +1 Even if the answer couldn't quite solve my problem, I think it's still helpful and shouldn't be deleted.